# gradle multi-project build using all 'project' dependenceis

Tags: java, scala, gradle, build-process, dependency-management

Background:
I have been developing a set of libraries in scala for my company.  The layout looks something like this:

```
   scala-libs\
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- settings.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-2
               +-- build.gradle
```

In our old development process, I would simply publish scala-lib-1.jar and scala-lib-2.jar to a local maven repo that we have, and dependent apps could just reference my libraries via compile dependencies.  For a number of reasons, we would like to convert this to a project dependency for the applications.

so, now we have this:

```
/root-dir
   +-- scala-libs
         +-- build.gradle <-- apply plugin scala
         +-- settings.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-2
               +-- build.gradle
   +-- java-libs
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- settings.gradle (references scala-libs using apply from: )
         +-- java-lib-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-lib-2
               +-- build.gradle
   +-- java-apps
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- settings.gradle (references java-apps using apply from: )
         +-- java-app-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-app-2
               +-- build.gradle
```

This doesn't appear to work because it doesn't pick up the parent build.gradle file in scala-libs to get the scala compiler config.

I think that the 'right' answer is to do something like this:

```
/root-dir
   +-- build.gradle
   +-- settings.gradle
   +-- scala-libs
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- scala-lib-2
               +-- build.gradle
   +-- java-libs
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-lib-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-lib-2
               +-- build.gradle
   +-- java-apps
         +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-app-1
               +-- build.gradle
         +-- java-app-2
               +-- build.gradle
```

Ideally, I could then issue: gradle :java-apps:java-app-2:build and have everything just compile.  My questions are:
* what goes in that top level settings.gradle?
* what goes in the top level build.gradle

I tried just getting one of the scala libs to compile in this 3-tier setup and ran into the following compiler error when I did gradle :scala-lib-1:compile from the new top level directory.

- What went wrong:

  A problem occurred evaluating project ':scala-lib-1'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'scala']
  >   Could not find property 'ideaProject' on task set.

I have no idea why it's looking for an ideaProject (I am applying the 'idea' plugin elsewhere, but not here).  It works fine if I do it from the scala-libs/ directory though.  I'm sure it's my limited groovy knowledge, but can anyone help with a simple example setup that can get us started?

Thanks!